# multiple form data submit at once

Tags: angularjs, json, http, parameters

I have got forms each laying in a collapsible panel wrapper in a page. Each of my forms are comprised of 3 or 4 form groups. Every one form of is controlled by a controller block. And finally, I have got different function blocks for each form groups.

Currently, once the fields are created and getting filled up, form group creates a .json file dynamically. (You can see this being in this .gif here: [DYNAMICALLY CREATED JSONS](http://g.recordit.co/RoM0dqcKe8.gif))

I have got an API, written in PHP; I'm sharing how insert and select work in .gif format as well respectively.(Currently api uses GET for everything in order to test it easily, so don't get surprised I'm aware of it.)  ( [INSERT](http://g.recordit.co/eiSkyCaU6M.gif), [SELECT AFTER INSERTION](http://g.recordit.co/j2hQu7HBkb.gif) )

What I need to do is, to post these to DB and committing at once if there's no error on aggregate of all JSONs and warn the user before commit if there's an error.

So hence, my question is how can I write a submit function that achieves to post these JSONs.

Below you can find my codes in snippet, it is not working here of course; but I'm sharing since I need a solution. At the end of my controller, I have a function named submitKisiIletisimBilgileri which currently concatenates all the JSONs and logs to the console. Instead of this, it needs to perform post by calling LocationService.AddField() a few times with different parameters. But I could not shape that part of my code; that is where I need help. :)

```js
app.controller('KisiIletisimBilgileri', ["$scope", "LocationService", function ($scope, LocationService) {

    $scope.phones = [{
        type: '',
        tel: ''
    }];
    $scope.addNewPhoneNumber = function () {
        $scope.phones.push({
            'type': '',
            'tel': ''
        });
        //  console.log(dataPhones);
    };
    $scope.removePhoneNumber = function (x) {
        // var lastItem = $scope.phones.length - 1;
        var index = $scope.phones.indexOf(x)

        if ($scope.phones.length > 1) //Never delete last one
            $scope.phones.splice(index, 1);
    };
    var dataPhones = $scope.phones;

    //Email Variables
    $scope.EmailTypeId = null;
    $scope.EmailTypeList = null;
    //Email Object & Functions
    $scope.mails = [{
        //id: '1',
        type: '',
        email: ''
    }];
    $scope.addNewEmailAddress = function () {
        //var newItemNo = $scope.mails.length + 1;
        $scope.mails.push({
            //'id': '' + newItemNo,
            'type': '',
            'email': '' //+ newItemNo
        });
    };
    $scope.removeEmailAddress = function (x) {
        // var lastItem = $scope.mails.length - 1;
        var index = $scope.mails.indexOf(x)

        if ($scope.mails.length > 1) //Never delete last one
            $scope.mails.splice(index, 1);
    };
    var dataMails = $scope.mails;

    //Media Variables
    $scope.MediaTypeId = null;
    $scope.MediaTypeList = null;
    //Media Object & Functions
    $scope.media = [{
        //id: '1',
        type: '',
        sma: ''
    }];
    $scope.addNewSMAccount = function () {
        //var newItemNo = $scope.media.length + 1;
        $scope.media.push({
            //'id': '' + newItemNo,
            'type': '',
            'sma': '' //+ newItemNo
        });
    };
    $scope.removeSMAccount = function (x) {
        // var lastItem = $scope.media.length - 1;
        var index = $scope.media.indexOf(x)

        if ($scope.media.length > 1) //Never delete last one
            $scope.media.splice(index, 1);
    };
    var dataMedia = $scope.media;

    $scope.submitKisiIletisimBilgileri = function () {

        var data = new Array();
        data.push(dataPhones);
        data.push(dataMails);
        data.push(dataMedia);

        /* post to server*/
        console.log(data);

    }



}]);
app.factory('LocationService', ["$http", function($http) {

    var fac = {};
    fac.AddField = function(q, t, c0, v0, c1, v1, c2, v2) {
        return $http.get('assets/api/kisiduzenle.php?q=' + q + '&t=' + t + '&c[0]=' + c0 + '&v[0]=' + v0 + '&c[1]=' + c1 + '&v[1]=' + v1 + '&c[2]=' + c2 + '&v[2]=' + v2);
    }
    return fac;
}]); //factory
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-white" id="paneliletisimbilgileri">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title text-primary">Kişi İletişim Bilgileri</h4>
        <ct-paneltool class="panel-tools" tool-collapse="tool-collapse"></ct-paneltool>
    </div>
    <div uib-collapse="paneliletisimbilgileri" ng-init="paneliletisimbilgileri=false" class="panel-wrapper">

        <form role="form" class="form-horizontal" ng-controller="KisiIletisimBilgileri">

            <!--PHONES-->

            <div class="form-group" data-ng-repeat="block in phones">

                <label class="col-sm-1 control-label" for="adsoyadunvan" ng-model="block">
                    Phone Number
                </label>
                <div class="col-sm-1">
                    <!--
                    <select class="form-control" ng-model="PhoneTypeId" ng-options="PhoneTypeList.COUNTRY_ID as PhoneTypeList.NAME for PhoneTypeList in PhoneTypeList" ng-change="GetPhoneType()">
                        <option value="" disabled="">Seçiniz</option>
                    </select>
-->
                    <span class="clip-select">
                            <select ng-model="block.type" name="country" class="form-control">
                                <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
                                <option value="Aktif">Aktif</option>
                                <option value="İş">İş</option>
                                <option value="Kişisel">Kişisel</option>
                                <option value="Cep">Cep</option>
                            </select>
                        </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">

                    <input type="text" ng-model="block.tel" id="adsoyadunvan" class="form-control underline" name="masked" ui-mask="(999) 999-9999" placeholder="(999) 999-9999">
                </div>


                <button class="col-md-offset-4 btn btn-red" href="#"><i class="fa fa-minus" ng-click="removePhoneNumber(block)"></i> </button>
            </div>
            <div id="phonesDisplay">
                <button class="col-md-offset-4 btn btn-azure" href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus" ng-click="addNewPhoneNumber()"></i> </button>
                <br>{{ phones }}
            </div>
            <!--PHONES-->

            <!--MAILS-->
            <div class="form-group" data-ng-repeat="block in mails">

                <label class="col-sm-1 control-label" for="adsoyadunvan" ng-model="block">
                    E-mail
                </label>
                <div class="col-sm-1">
                    <span class="clip-select">
                            <select ng-model="block.type" name="country" class="form-control">
                                <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
                                <option value="Aktif">Aktif</option>
                                <option value="İş">İş</option>
                                <option value="Kişisel">Kişisel</option>
                            </select>
                        </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <input type="email" ng-model="block.email" id="adsoyadunvan" class="form-control underline" name="masked" placeholder="abc@abc.com">
                </div>


                <button class="col-md-offset-4 btn btn-red" href="#"><i class="fa fa-minus" ng-click="removeEmailAddress(block)"></i> </button>
            </div>
            <div id="mailsDisplay">
                <button class="col-md-offset-4 btn btn-azure" href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus" ng-click="addNewEmailAddress()"></i> </button>
                <br>{{ mails }}
            </div>
            <!--MAILS-->

            <!--SOCIAL MEDIA-->
            <div class="form-group" data-ng-repeat="block in media">

                <label class="col-sm-1 control-label" for="adsoyadunvan" ng-model="block">
                    Social Media Account
                </label>
                <div class="col-sm-1">
                    <span class="clip-select">
                            <select ng-model="block.type" name="country" class="form-control">
                                <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
                                <option value="Facebook">Facebook</option>
                                <option value="Twitter">Twitter</option>
                                <option value="Instagram">Instagram</option>
                            </select>
                        </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="block.sma" id="adsoyadunvan" class="form-control underline">
                </div>


                <button class="col-md-offset-4 btn btn-red" href="#"><i class="fa fa-minus" ng-click="removeSMAccount(block)"></i> </button>
            </div>
            <div id="mediaDisplay">
                <button class="col-md-offset-4 btn btn-azure" href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus" ng-click="addNewSMAccount()"></i> </button>
                <br>{{ media }}
            </div>
            <!--SOCIAL MEDIA-->
            <div>
                <button class="col-md-offset-4 btn btn-green" href="#"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane" ng-click="submitKisiIletisimBilgileri()"></i> </button>
            </div>

        </form>


    </div>

</div>
```

EDIT 1: I have updated my submit function as below

```
$scope.submitKisiIletisimBilgileri = function () {
    $scope.myForm.$setSubmitted();
    if ($scope.myForm.$invalid) {
        alert("There's something invalid in one of the forms!");
    } else {
        ///api/kisiduzenle.php?q=add&t=telefon&c[0]=KISILIK_ID&v[0]=119486&c[1]=TELEFON&v[1]=888888888&c[2]=TIP&v[2]=W
        var urlParams = {
            q: 'add',
            t: 'telefon',
            c0: 'KISILIK_ID',
            v0: '119486',
            c1: 'TELEFON',
            v1: '8888888888',
            c2: 'TIP',
            v2: 'W'
        }

        var data = new Array();
        data.push(dataPhones);
        data.push(dataMails);
        data.push(dataMedia);

        LocationService.AddField(urlParams, data);
    }
}
```

EDIT 2: While my function in my LocationService is like this..

```
  fac.AddField = function (urlParams, formData) {
    var request = {
        method: 'GET'
        url: 'assets/api/kisiduzenle.php?q=' + urlParams.q + '&t=' + urlParams.t + '&c[0]=' + urlParams.c0 + '&v[0]=' + urlParams.v0 + '&c[1]=' + urlParams.c1 + '&v[1]=' + urlParams.v1 + '&c[2]=' + urlParams.c2 + '&v[2]=' + urlParams.v2
        data: formData,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you should name your form to get access from your controller. Optionally use `ngForm` directive for nested forms - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm - it's really helpfull. If one of your nested forms is invalid, then your parent form is also invalid.

```
<form name="myForm">
<!-- first nested form -->
   <div ng-form="firstNestedForm">
   </div>
<!-- second nested form -->
   <div ng-form="secondNestedForm">
   </div>
<!-- etc. -->
   ...
</form>
```

Afterwards update your function `submitKisiIletisimBilgileri` to look like this

```
$scope.submitKisiIletisimBilgileri = function () {
    $scope.myForm.$setSubmitted();
    if($scope.myForm.$invalid){
       // alert user
    }else{
      // gather your forms data and post it to server
    }
}
```

It is important to properly set your form, because `$scope.myForm.$invalid` depends on it. If there won't be any validators on your inputs etc. or `required` attribute, then your form will be always valid.

Read more here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController and
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

Your $http request should look like this

```
var request = {},
    formData = {data: []};

formData.data.push(dataPhones);
formData.data.push(dataMails);
formData.data.push(dataMedia);

request = { 
  method: 'POST'                 // or GET... it depends on you API
  url: 'http://myapi.com/form'   // your API url
  headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/json'   // here you can place authorization token etc.
  },                     
  data: formData                 // your form data to post on server
}

$http(request).then(function(response){
   // do something on success
},function(error){
   // do something on error
});
```

or using your `LocationService`

```
app.factory('LocationService', ["$http", function($http) {
    var fac = {};
    fac.AddField = function(formData) {
        var request = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'assets/api/kisiduzenle.php',
            params: formData
        }

        return $http(request);
    }
    return fac;
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'll be reading these two topics. Please help me with forming my $http.get in the right manner so that I can move on. How can I give the data to that function as parameter?

Comment: could you please give me a hand on this?

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll give a try and let you know about the results in here.

Comment: What I do not understand here is, how I am going to send both my parameters and data at the same time? I mean sending data: formData and params {...} at the same time is logical ??? If you have a look to my API, it is accepting parameters in an array form and performing one DB row insertion at a time. Is it better to use it in this way or I need to update the API to accept multiple rows at a time as well.

Comment: I can't see your API - 403 forbidden

Comment: if you click on browser line and hit enter or reload the URL, it is coming.

Comment: I'll try to apply this. I'll let you know about the results. Thanks again.

Comment: @ybaylav I have opened your *.gif on my phone (can't open it at work) and now I can see how it works. Your API doesn't need $http request data, because it is using query params. You need too pass your formData as parameters in your url.

Comment: So do I need to parse OR serialize the formData somehow and pass it as in parameter format? How can I manage that? When I'm giving it in the format that you have just messaged me in the LocationService ( .. method:..,url: .., data: formData ..), is not parsing the formData into parameters while performing the $http request??

Comment: @ybaylav pass your formData to $http.params  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializer
But remember that your formData object must match your api url params, otherwise it won't work, and you'll have to write your own serialize function $http.paramSerializer or format your formData object to fit your api.

Comment: That was I was thinking about it might work. So as you confirmed my guess, I'll try it. So then, in this case I'll send only urlParams to my LocationService.AddField function. And concatenate the $httpParamSerializer functions result to my urlParams, right?

Comment: @ybaylav I have updated LocationService above. Just pass formData to $http.params and it should concatenate it to your url.

Comment: I have put 2 edits under your answer part. (I'm not sure that's sth true for StackOverflow but..) What do you think of this??? Is this a right method? If it is not how can I pass formData to $http.params ?? Do I still need to use $httpParamSerializer  in this case??

Comment: I have put my edits at the end of my question part. Awaiting for your help on my question above.

Comment: I'm trying to form it but I'll share all my code to you with a plunker link. http://plnkr.co/edit/Rp77G3aOEe6OGEzODDDC?p=info  I need to send all of the form information by calling this API in this format multiple times.**/api/kisiduzenle.php?q=add&t=telefon&c[0]=KISILIK_ID&v[0]=119486&c[1]=TELEFON&v[1]=888888888&c[2]=TIP&v[2]=W** And data for each will be like {
            'type': '',
            'tel': ''
        } as you can see in the code as well.

Comment: Hence the current form data is concatenated apples and bananas. I need them differentiated somehow. Or sent differently to AddField for each form but submitted if at once if there's no error at all.

Comment: @ybaylav send me your email adress, we shouldn't chat here

Answer (score -1):

I'm not really familiar with angular but... Why not use jQuery inside your function?

`var formData = $( "#testform" ).serialize();`

Comment: Honestly I'm not familiar with jQuery at all. This could be an option, but as far as I follow the new web development trend pushes jQuery to deprecated technologies basket. So why use an old car instead of learning the right angular way ? :)

Comment: It is considered bad practice to use jquery methods in an angular controller. Angular is about data binding with ngModel in forms. You should never have to use any jquery in an Angular controller to make a form work.

Comment: For that reason wrote: "I'm not familiar with angular". I prefer VUE instead. We agree that there are better technologies for each case, but to say that is doomed..is a little risky in my opinion.